# Debugging Test Environment w/ IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

We are in the process of setting up IdentityServer4. Our dev environment is working but it is not clear how this will work in other environments (Test/UAT/Production/etc).

The dev instance is able to work because we are fine with putting localhost resources (clients/apis) in the database. This allows us to have an Angular app with an implicit flow that redirects to http://ourdevserver.com (as an example) and get a token that we can then use with either dev apis or local apis/clients that are being debugged on localhost.

Once we start moving to other non-dev environments, we do not want to have localhost resources in the database (for obvious reasons). Does this mean that we will not be able to debug any environment outside of our dev server? It seems like it would be valuable to debug a client against a production resource under certain conditions but I am not sure how to achieve this in a way that doesn't compromise security.

Comment: In the extreme situations that I've had to debug against testing or staging environments, I've found that modifying my hosts file for local DNS overrides has been sufficient.

Comment: It's pretty rare that you would need to debug against a production environment. I can't remember I time I've needed to do that. We have a separate database for each environment that holds different identity server clients specific to that environment. Would that work for you? Are you saying you have one database with clients for all environments?